# Why does the value of a block of memory which stores a integer change repeatedly?

Tags: c++, pointers, point

First of all, I define an integer pointer and class `A`. I want to pass a pointer to `A`'s method to store it.

I found that the integer member of class `A` always changes when I invoke a method of `A`.

I'm confused about how to avoid those changes.

```
#include <IOSTREAM>

using namespace std;

class   A
{
private:
   int* a;
public:
   A()
   {

   };
   ~A()
   {

   };

void setA(int n)
{
    cout << "n == " << n << "&n == " << &n << endl;
    a = &n;
    cout << "now a== " << a << endl;
}

void PassA(int* &outint)
{
    cout << "a == " << a <<  "  *a == " << *a <<endl;
    outint = a;
    cout << "outint = " << outint << endl;
}

void Print()
{
    cout << "a ==================== " << a << endl;
    cout << "*a ==================== " << *a << endl;
}
};

int main()
{
A A_1;
int num = 5;
    A_1.setA(num);

    int *intb= NULL ;
    A_1.PassA(intb);
    //When the line above done,the value of A_1.a will change.
    cout << "intb ==  " << intb << endl;
    cout << "*intb =="  << *intb << endl;
    cout << "num ==" << num << endl;
A_1.Print();
return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
n == 5&n == 0x28fe90
now a== 0x28fe90
a == 0x28fe90  *a == 2686708
outint = 0x28fe90
intb ==  0x28fe90
*intb ==4619604
num ==5
a ==================== 0x28fe90
*a ==================== 4619604
```

Comment: Why are you worried about how memory is being allocated for you as long as it is allocated?

Comment: I just want to make the pointer which define in the main() point to the same address as a class member pointer point to.

Comment: It is dangerous to keep hold of the variables which are on `stack`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting a memory location to a value that is on the stack. Stack values will be discarded when the method ends. If you must allocate your own memory, do it using new and delete:

```
void setA(int n)
{
    cout << "n == " << n << "&n will be different every time" << endl;
    a = new int();
    *a = n;
    cout << "now a== " << a << endl;
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to use an actual address of a variable in the callee, you would need to pass in an int pointer rather than an int:

```
void setA(int* n)
{
    cout << "n == " << *n << " &n = " << n << endl;
    a = n;
    cout << "now a== " << a << endl;
}
```

Comment: `n` could also be a reference; then, taking the address of that reference would result in a pointer valid until the execution of the function of the variable it pointed to (presumably the caller function's) ended.

Comment: @Andy.G Apart from just solving this issue, it's important to understand that local variables are allocated on the stack, and dynamically allocated variables by you use the heap. Understand the underlying concepts, so next time you know what is going on.

Comment: @Csaba Toth Yes, the key is the difference between stack and heap, I would always keep in mind.